# View.setVisibility ignored when loading data

Tags: java, android, android-layout

View.setVisibility does not work in specific cases. Here is an example:

Works fine:

```
void A()
{
    View1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    View2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

SetVisibility ignored, rest executed:

```
void B()
{
    View1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    View2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    for (String path: dataPaths)
    {
        // Loading data
    }
}
```

I tried:

- Call sections separately
- Move data loading to jni so that the java part only sets setView and calls the jni function
- [Async Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)
- [invalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#invalidate()) and [postInvalidate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#postInvalidate())

Comment: Are you sure that you dont change views inside the cycle?

Comment: I am sure. That section only reads and validates data from storage.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please, provide the code from // Loading data. Mb it is lock UI thread.

Comment: @Yegorf, I have edited the question. jni function is called after the loop. SetVisibility does not work during the entire execution of the function. In jni are called opencv data processing functions. After returning from the function, setVisibility works again.

Comment: Well, its a riddle. I will wait for the answer with you :)

Comment: your code is performing potentially expensive I/O and image processing tasks on the UI thread, things that should be done on a background thread.  What specifically did you try via AsyncTask?, this seems to be the right direction

Comment: @CSmith, Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I have tried more variants using AsyncTask. It didn't work, but I found and tried [Runnable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable) thanks to that and now it works. If you write it in the answer, I will accept it and edit it so it contains the code that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is performing potentially expensive I/O and image processing tasks on the UI thread, this is why your Visibility calls appear to not work...you're effectively hanging all UI updates while this expensive work is being performed.

Threading and background processing is complex.  `AsyncTask` was once a popular means of doing simple background tasks but it's been marked deprecated as of API 30.

**Suggested reading:**

https://developer.android.com/guide/background

You'll want to learn how to dispatch work to a background thread, then how the background thread can dispatch UI updates back to the main thread when complete.

Additionally you might consider using `WorkManager` as a way of scheduling and managing background tasks:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

The [Guide to background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) offers suggestions on this also.